# Full Traceback with pytest-check?

Tags: python, pytest

ex_code.py

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("num",[99,81])
def test_one(num):
    for x in range(3):
        assert num == x

@pytest.mark.parametrize("num",[99,81])
def test_two(num):
    for x in range(3):
        with check: assert num == x
```

results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfdv1.png

as you can see, test_one has a detailed traceback but using a context manager, no more traceback. In the docs it's stated that tracebacks are only done for default tests ->

> assert: ....

Especially for @pytest.mark.parameterize, the explicit variable definition is very helpful

is there a way around this? Ideally just print the traceback once per test function?

Comment: Where is `check` defined and what does it do with exceptions?

Comment: @Oin ah good point, here is the doc: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-check/ 

(context manager use case is lower on the page)

Answer (score 0):

The `pytest-check` library [hides tracebacks in the contextmanagers](https://github.com/okken/pytest-check/blob/2e2670d0a0bb5319e90799e12436015444456f11/src/pytest_check/check_methods.py#L48-L91). You can see the use of `__tracebackhide__ = True` there.

You can try disabling that by using the `--full-trace` command line option.

You can read more about `__tracebackhide__` in the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/simple.html#writing-well-integrated-assertion-helpers).

Comment: good find! that said, it makes the failure statements unreadable. Here's the traceback before each failure: https://pastebin.com/Cgb90RFf
Also, it doens't actually traceback for the "with check" usage (even though it should according to docs): https://i.imgur.com/xPm39Qs.png